# How to configure constructor injection in NServiceBus

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, nservicebus

I have what would seem to be a relatively common scenario. I need to inject a dependency which  requires a constructor.

I have a repository that looks like this:

```
public class ApprovalRepository : IApprovalRepository
{
    private readonly MongoCollection<Approval> _collection;

    public ApprovalRepository(MongoDatabase database)
    {
        this._collection = database.GetCollection<Approval>("Approvals");
    }

    // ...
}
```

An endpoint config that looks like this:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, 
    AsA_Server, IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        NServiceBus.Configure.With().DefaultBuilder().JsonSerializer();
    }
}
```

And a handler that looks like this:

```
public class PlaceApprovalHandler : IHandleMessages<PlaceApproval>
{
    public IApprovalRepository ApprovalRepository { get; set; }

    public void Handle(PlaceApproval message)
    {
        //
        ApprovalRepository.Save(
            new Approval
                {
                    Id = message.Id, 
                    Message = message.MessageText, 
                    ProcessedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
                });
    }
}
```

I then have a class to do the custom initialization:

```
public class ConfigureDependencies : IWantCustomInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        // configure Mongo
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/?safe=true");
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("ServiceBusTest");

        Configure.Instance.Configurer.RegisterSingleton<IApprovalRepository>(new ApprovalRepository(database));
    }
}
```

The result is an error:

```
2013-04-11 17:01:03,945 [Worker.13] WARN  NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus [(null)] <(null)> - PlaceApprovalHandler failed handling message.
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: Circular component dependency detected: Server.PlaceApprovalHandler -> Server.ApprovalRepository -> Server.ApprovalRepository.
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.CircularDependencyDetector.CheckForCircularDependency(IComponentRegistration registration, Stack`1 activationStack, Int32 callDepth) in :line 0
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) in :line 0
```

I'm not that familiar with Autofac. I also tried the following, which also had a similar result:

```
Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent(() => new ApprovalRepository(database), DependencyLifecycle.SingleInstance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my ApprovalRepository, some odd code had crept in, namely:

```
#region Public Properties

public IApprovalRepository Repository { get; set; }

#endregion
```

NServiceBus was then trying to automatically inject that property. As a result the ApprovalRepository took in an IApprovalRepository. Ooops. My bad. This now explains the error:

```
Server.PlaceApprovalHandler -> Server.ApprovalRepository -> Server.ApprovalRepository
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the concrete types you're trying to inject into the handlers should be unknown to the endpoint itself.

https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Scanning

I like selecting my types via "opt-in" by putting a custom attribute on the class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class RegisterServiceAttribute : Attribute {}
```

Then select the types like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (RegisterServiceAttribute), false).Any())
    .AsSelf()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

As an example of what I do:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, IWantCustomInitialization, AsA_Server, UsingTransport<SqlServer>
{
    public void Init()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(GetAllAssemblies())
            .Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ProviderAttribute), false).Any())
            .AsSelf()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        Configure
            .With()
            .UseTransport<SqlServer>()
            .AutofacBuilder(builder.Build())
            .UseNHibernateTimeoutPersister()
            .UseNHibernateSagaPersister()
            .UnicastBus();
    }

    private static Assembly[] GetAllAssemblies()
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        return Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll").Select(Assembly.LoadFile).ToArray();
    }
}
```